# NameError in UsersController - (uninitialized constant SCrypt)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

In my Rails app using **Rails 4.1.0** and **Ruby 2.1.0**,

I have been authenticating users using **Authlogic**.

In `users_controller.rb`, I have a create method as given below.

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params) #this line has the error
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to_target_or_default account_url, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
    end
  end
end
```

Since strong parameters are strongly recommended in Rails 4.0, `attr_accessible` is removed from `User` model and below given code added to **users_controller.rb**.

```
private

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:login, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role_ids)
    end
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  #attr_accessible :login, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role_ids

  has_many :articles
  has_many :comments
  has_many :assignments

  has_many :roles, :through => :assignments

  def role_symbols
    roles.map do |role|
      role.name.underscore.to_sym
    end
  end


  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.login_field = :login
  end


  def deliver_password_reset_instructions!
    reset_perishable_token!
    Notifier.deliver_password_reset_instructions(self)
  end

end
```

Now, when I try to register using the form given below,

[image]

I'm getting the below attached error. Please help me to have a solution.

[image]

Comment: `SCrypt` is a Ruby gem, I suppose you use it for password hashing? You probably do not have the gem installed, or it is not added to your Gemfile. https://rubygems.org/gems/scrypt

Comment: Can you post you user model. SCrypt is used by authlogic to decrypt the password. This is getting called, but not found. I would check your that your implementation of authlogic is correct. Are you sure the authlogic gem supports rails 4.1 and ruby 2.1.1

Comment: @Andreas Lyngstad: question updated. I hope Authlogic supports Rails 4.0

Comment: @Rajesh C O perhaps you should accept my answer for future reference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From this [issue](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/issues/400) on the authlogic github account

Authlogic has changed its default encryption system from SHA512 to SCrypt.

It seems that you need this in your gemfile

```
gem 'authlogic', '~> 3.4.0'
gem 'scrypt'
```

If you don't want SCrypt you can use Sha512 by putting this

```
acts_as_authentic do |c|
  c.crypto_provider = Authlogic::CryptoProviders::Sha512
end
```

in your User.rb

You also might need to specify the version of the authlogic gem

```
gem 'authlogic', github: 'binarylogic/authlogic', ref: 'e4b2990d6282f3f7b50249b4f639631aef68b939'
```

but I guess this will be fixed soon

Comment: What's in your gemfile

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the Authlogic gem. To make it supported by **Rails 4.0**, we need to get it from below given github URL,

```
gem 'authlogic', github: 'binarylogic/authlogic', ref: 'e4b2990d6282f3f7b50249b4f639631aef68b939'
```

Then the implementation of Strong parameters also works fine..